# How to print text when camera captures blue color?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm working on a script using opencv and python to print text when the camera captures a certain color. I tried to use an `if` statement, but it fails.

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
    result = lower_blue + upper_blue

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    if result.any() == True:
       print 'I can see blue color'

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what kind of matrix you're actually getting in `hsv` variable?

Comment: According to [this tool](http://www.colorpicker.com/) a hue value of 110..130 corresponds to green.

Comment: @Falko, H value in CV_8UC3 images is halved, so it's in range [0,180]. [110,130] _is_ blue

Comment: @WGH it'll be a mat of type CV_8UC3

Comment: @shar, you probably want to do `res.any()`, instead of `result.any()`

Comment: you could also look at sum of the `mask` as a rough estimate of the amount of blue pixels. Something like `count = mask.sum()` and check that against a certain threshold to be sure you actually have a blue object and not just perhaps one blue pixel.

Comment: @scorreia you're right. OpenCV provides `cv2.countNonZero(src) → retval` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a solution that works for my environment. I'm using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4.6. you may need to modify the `blue_threshold` value to suit your needs.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
blue_threshold = 1000000  # This value you could change for what works best

while True:

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    count = mask.sum()

    if count > blue_threshold:
       print 'I can see blue color'


    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```